# How to find last merge in git?

Tags: git

For a web site, I have master and staging, I have worked on staging for about 10 days. How do I tell for sure what has changed since my last merge, or when that merge was? Most of the merges I have done end up being FFs so I can't log them like `git merge branch -m 'merging staging'` (git reports it ignored -m). I usually merge master into staging for testing before merging staging into master for more testing and deployment.

I could tag each one but I'm worried about the clutter of doing that for merges.  What I'd like to know is "roughly, what changed since my last merge of staging into master?" Then I could make sure I spent extra time investigating those changes in the final examination. Sometimes co-workers make changes I hadn't noticed until this stage.

I suppose since staging->into->master merges are rare, I could tag them and then do a "git whatchanged tag" but I'm hoping there is a non-tag way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: That's why I always avoid fast-forward merges...

Comment: @CharlesB: How do I avoid them? If I'm on staging, do I avoid merging master into it, and only merge staging into master?

Comment: @CharlesB: ah, I see, --no-ff? I'll have to try that...

Comment: @Hans: In general, you don't want to merge master into other branches, but rather the other way around.

Comment: @Jefromi: I do this because we have been hotfixing things in a branch which we merge into master and publish. After doing a few of these, we merge master into any development/staging branches. Would it be better to merge the hotfixes directly? And, what is better about it? Thanks.

Comment: In general it's always best to merge the smallest thing that's what you want. This prevents you from ever ending up in a situation where, say, you merge master into a feature branch, and pull in all kinds of other stuff you don't actually need. It sounds like your situation is at relatively low risk of this... except your question is about being aware of all the changes that everyone has merged in, and [merging upstream](http://gitster.livejournal.com/42247.html) is a good way to really know what you should have.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this, it will select the last branch where the commit message starts with "Merge":

```
git show :/^Merge
```

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20111122032830/http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/07/git-tips/)'s a website with a few git tips that might help you out.

Comment: @alex, thanks for the answer. For some reason, if I'm on a non-master branch and I "merge master" into it, it logs a commit message, but if I'm on master and merge that branch (eg, staging), it doesn't, because it's a fast-forward.

Comment: I think what you really want to do is `git log --merges -n 1`. There's actually no guarantee that a merge commit has a commit message of this form, even though it's the default.

Comment: That's awesome. I don't know how I missed that, looking around for hours, but that's what I wanted. Incidentally, I can't tell, does it show the ff merges? I want to know when I merged, so using --no-ff in master is probably still good, right?

Comment: Also: how can I show the branchname so it shows in gitk or terminal version of gitk (k = log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr, %cd) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset')? Does git store the branch name as it was when committed, or would I have to add that in the log msg?

Comment: @Hans: A fast-forward merge is not a merge commit, so no, `git log --merges` won't show it. The only record of a fast-forward merge is in the reflog; it's not a real tracked part of the repository in any way. If those fast-forwards are things you actually want to record permanently, then yes, you need to use `--no-ff` to force them to be recorded as merge commits.

Comment: @Hans: I'm not sure what you mean by "show the branchname". You mean the branch you merged into another? That's not really how git thinks: it merges *commits*. A branch is just a way to specify a commit. The default merge commit message (which is also generated when you use `--no-ff`) does include the merged branch name in its subject.

Answer (score 42):

```
git log --merges -n 1
```

works well. From `man git-log`:

```
   --merges
       Print only merge commits. This is exactly the same as --min-parents=2.
```

Here's an example using `--pretty=format:"%H"` to get just the SHA.

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%H" --merges -n 1
f32e1f13eef7d5843e8063b8709d01af6dcd5dbf
```

Credit goes to [Jefromi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119963/jefromi) for their [comment on another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898837/how-to-find-last-merge-in-git#comment5456299_4898869).

Comment: $ git show :/^Merge --pretty=format:"%H"   returns: 1a2ccd458d1f19167b9eb2ea11a70cccac6ba4d4

Answer (score 13):

An alternative which does not rely on the content of the commit message:

```
$ git rev-list --min-parents=2 --max-count=1 HEAD
9c6e6d6b6b9bd293335700e34e05217ae8e7a7e8
```

`--min-parents=2` selects only commits which are merges, `--max-count=1` only shows the first commit when going back in history. If the specified commit (`HEAD`) does not have any merge commits in its history, the output will be empty.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is my best bet:

I edited ~/.gitconfig, adding:

```
[branch "master"]
    mergeoptions = --no-ff
```

Then if I'm on master and I merge in a branch, it shows it as a full merge. Having that as a config option for just "master" shows how awesome git is, so I can still FF merges within branches, where I'm likely to have a lot of short-lived topic branches, and I don't have to remember to specify --no-ff when merging on master. Beautiful.

I use this alias for viewing logs:

k = log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr, %cd) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit

```
> git k (similar to the gui gitk, but stays in the terminal)
```

When I view logs that way, it paints a nice picture of the branching. If I want to find the last one, I can do

```
> git show :/"Merge branch 'staging'"
```

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: As @jefromi noted in the comments to the first answer, this is probably a better technique `git log --merges -n 1`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't really want to know **what is changed since last merge**, but **what have I on branch *staging* that is not yet on branch *master*?** (or the other way around). If so, look at the command `git cherry`.

Though I must confess I never used this command because of the output format, which is not really helpful. Maybe there is a way to feed this output to git log/git show or such.

---

**Edit**: As I understand, you don't need a tag to use `git whatchanged`. Try simply `git whatchanged master..staging` to see what changed on staging since you last merged from staging to master.

Comment: ŭlo - that's another good one. For this question, not allowing FF merges in master and using good log output format helps me mostly -- as does the `git show:/"Merge"` trick, but I've also been using `git log master..staging` which seems similar to `git whatchanged master..staging`

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply diff your staging branch against master? That will show you the actual differences in each of your files, and not only those unmerged stuff. Also things you may have dropped when merging from staging to master in the past.

try `git diff master..staging`
or `git diff master...staging` to see the diff from their common ancestor to 'staging'.

Answer (score 0):

Take the latest merge and give branch name which merged to current branch

MC=`git log --merges -n 1 | grep request`; BB=${MC##*:}; B=${BB%% *}; SUBBRANCH=${B##*/}
echo $MC