# Use difftool after doing git pull

Tags: git

I have just done `git pull` and I would like to use `git difftool` (p4v in my case) to compare after my commit and now/the pull. I have not pushed the merged code yet.

I don't want to have to go looking up revision numbers (or gitlab) etc, surely it should be possible to use the `git difftool`, may be with an argument, to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not pushed the changes yet, you could use

```
git difftool master origin/master
```

To find the last merge commit, you could use

```
git log --merges -n 1
```

(see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44712764/10805404) for more information).

You could then use the following command:

```sh
git difftool master $(git log --merges -n 1 --pretty=format:%H)
```