# Need to get commit SHA id of latest merge in GitPython

Tags: git, gitpython

My default branch in git is 'develop' branch.

I want to get commit-id of latest merged branch to my 'develop' branch.
Is it possible with git python ?

on commandline I can do

```
git log | grep Merge
```

and then pick the latest one.
Is there a way to do this with gitpython ?

Thanks.

Comment: fyi, on the command line `git log -1 --merges`.

Comment: @jthill
Thanks, this is exactly what I am looking for with gitpython.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have the branch HEAD commit (`headcommit = repo.head.commit`), you can:

- check its number of parents: `len(headcommit.parents)`
- if one, takes its only parent: `headcommit.parents[0]`

Repeat until you find a commit with more than one parent: it will be your merge commit.
That would emulate [`git log --merges -n 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44712764/6309).

The OP recommends:

```
headcommit = repo.head.commit 
while True: 
  headcommit = headcommit.parents[0] 
  if len(headcommit.parents) is not 1: break 
print (headcommit
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
I just tried it, 
```

but it gives me commit sha id of my last commit.
Not the last "Merge" commit.

Comment: @Mr.Axe If your last commit is a merge commit, that would be expected. But if your mast commit has only one parent, then you must loop and take its parent, repeat the test there.

Comment: @Mr.Axe Well done. I have included your comment/code in the answer for more visibility.